# Prove there is no complex number $|z|-z=i$

Tags: complex-numbers

Prove that there is no complex number $z$ such that $|z|-z=i$

How do I go about proving it? I tried expanding it in term of $z=a+bi$ but it gets me nowhere.

Answer (score 6):

The decmposition $z=|z|-i$ is in fact the decomposition into real and imaginary part, i.e., $z=a+bi$ with $a=|z|$ and $b=-1$. Then 
$$|z|^2=|a+bi|^2=a^2+b^2=|z|^2+1^2 $$
contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that both $i$ and $j$ mean the same thing, i.e. the imaginary unit.

Setting $z=a+bi$, your equation becomes $$\sqrt{a^2+b^2} - (a+bi)=i\\
(\sqrt{a^2+b^2} - a) + (-b)i = 0 + 1i$$

Now, remember that $x+yi=u+vi$ if and only if $x=u$ and $y=v$. Write down the two equations you get from this.